# Errors when running Disk Utility on APFS SSD (error: doc-id tree, volume corrupt)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, ssd, filesystem, apfs

On my Mac running Disk Utility / First aid produces errors that Disk Utility doesn't seem to be able to fix (full log at bottom).

First:

> Checking the fsroot tree. 
> error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 8886, file-id 73099842 but no inode references this doc-id

Completely blank here. Is there a way to identify the actual file from the info given? What are other ways to fix this?

Second:

> Verifying volume object map space. 
> The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.

Not sure if this corruption refers to the error above or something else. What even is the "volume object map space"?

To be clear, I have not experienced any issues yet, but the line "*The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.*" has me worried about the state of my SSD. Also, while it says that the volume "*appears to be OK*" at the end, the error persists even after running First Aid multiple times.

What I find odd is that Disk Utility seems to be saying that everything is fine ("*exit code is 0.*" and "*Operation successful.*"), when clearly something is not quite right.

I have a 2018 Macbook Pro running Ventura 13.4.1. The disk in question is an APFS Data Volume formatted using APFS (Encrypted).

[image]

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

**FULL LOG**

> Running First Aid on “Data (APFS)” (disk1s5) 
>
> Verifying the startup volume will cause this computer to stop responding. 
>
> Verifying file system. 
> Volume could not be unmounted. 
> Using live mode. 
> Performing fsck_apfs -n -l -x /dev/rdisk1s5 
> Checking the container superblock. 
> Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 37375279. 
> Checking the EFI jumpstart record. 
> Checking the space manager. 
> Checking the space manager free queue trees. 
> Checking the object map. 
> Checking the encryption key structures. 
> Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s5. 
> Checking the APFS volume superblock. 
> The volume Data (APFS) was formatted by diskmanagementd (1677.120.9) and last modified by apfs_kext (2142.120.7). 
> Checking the object map. 
> Checking the snapshot metadata tree. 
> Checking the snapshot metadata. 
> Checking the document ID tree. 
> **Checking the fsroot tree. 
>
> error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 8886, file-id 73099842 but no inode references this doc-id** 
>
> Checking the extent ref tree. 
> **Verifying volume object map space. 
>
> The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.** 
> Verifying allocated space. 
> Performing deferred repairs. 
> The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 appears to be OK. 
> File system check exit code is 0. 
> Restoring the original state found as mounted.
>
> Operation successful.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have "solved" this by wiping my entire SSD and restoring from a Time Machine backup. While initially everything was fine, I have noticed that when I install Xcode a new warning shows up, saying "warning: inode (id 2411715): Resource Fork xattr is missing for compressed file" and , again, "The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.". I reproduced this by installing / uninstalling Xcode multiple times. This makes me believe that the assessment of Disk Utility about disk corruption is probably not quite right.